# Trouble using Net::Ping

Tags: perl, ping

I am using Net::Ping to check the network availability. When I run the code, it returns response. But when I recheck using command prompt, it is time out.

The Code :

```
$p = Net::Ping->new('tcp');
$p->hires();
($ret, $duration, $ip) = $p->ping($host);
if ($ret){
printf("$host [ip: $ip] is alive (packet return time: %.2f ms)\n", 1000 * $duration);
}else{
printf("time out");
}
```

Result :

10.10.x.x [ip: 10.10.x.x] is alive (packet return time: 18.72 ms)

Using command prompt :

C:\ping 10.10.x.x -t

Pinging 10.10.x.x with 32 bytes of data:

Request timed out.

Any explanation and advice would be appreciated

Comment: `ping` uses ICMP, maybe the host blocks that but allows the TCP connection from `Net::Ping`

Comment: What if you use  $p = Net::Ping->new('icmp');   You will have to run it as root.

Comment: thanks robearl and szabgab.. it works :)